# Active state and display:none causes link not to work

Tags: html, css

Consider the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GMA76/

On the links active state I want to replace the content of the a tag, then it should continue to follow the link. However when I style it as shown in the fiddle and here:

```
a div:first-child{
    display:block;
}
a div:last-child{
    display:none;
}
a:active div:first-child{
    display:none;
}
a:active div:last-child{
    display:block;
}
```

The link doesn't work the first time you click it. It only replaces the content and then it seems the redirection fails.

How would I fix that?

Comment: Maybe it is because the click event not working on disabled elements...

Comment: A simpler logic would be to replace div which you want to dynamically add within the anchor tag, than keeping 2 tags

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't take well to content changing on the `:active` event. Even if it did work, a CSS-only solution would likely mean that the user wouldn't even see the change in content before the new page had loaded (or started to load with a white screen). I tested a lot with the `:after` pseudo-selector and the `content` property, but this didn't work either.

And rightly so. Changes to content should *only* be done with a language like Javascript. This is a logic issue and is outside of the scope of a styling language. Therefore, I would suggest using Javascript.

I've created a quick [***fiddle here***](http://jsfiddle.net/zryAT/3/) using Javascript with jQuery (doesn't need jQuery it but it's easier) to switch the text in the link and then go to the new page exactly 1 second afterwards. This way you only need to have the original link in the HTML rather than hiding separate links with CSS. There are more flexible and extensible ways to do this if it's not just for one or two links but for the sake of an example, take a look at the fiddle.

This is the jQuery:

```
$(".switch-link").click(function(){
    $(this).text("Test Two");
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = href
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

`1000` is the delay between the text changing and the browser starting to load the new page, you can change this to suit your needs.

Comment: Buddy, The OP has not even tagged JavaScript and you are providing a jQuery solution

Comment: His question is of DOM manipulation and Javascript is the best solution.

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree at this point. Dont take the -1 from me personally

Comment: No worries, it's healthy to disagree. I'll look into a CSS-only solution but if the OP is looking at manipulating the DOM in this project then I think that highlighting Javascript solutions is very helpful.

Comment: Glad to see you took the critism well. I Would take my downvote back immediately if you came up with a CSS only solution or maybe even a simple javascript one. Somehow i feel jQuery is an overkill for this

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't think a CSS-only solution will be possible (after trying many times) and whether it's tagged or not, Javascript should be used to make changes to a page's contents. You don't have to agree but IMO if someone posts a question about language A and the only solution is language B, I don't think that bringing it to attention deserves a downvote, it's better than no-one answering at all.

Comment: To be honest I was not looking for a JavaScript solution, as I know how to do that. It is really not manipulation of the DOM, as this corresponds to hover effect. Doing that with JavaScript would not b best practice. IMO this should be possible.

Comment: Okay, no worries Jens. Changing the text of a link on any sort of event is good practice and recommended, that's why all of the JS events and manipulation methods exist. If it was a CSS problem then there'd be a CSS solution. That said, I'm sorry I couldn't help you further and good luck with the project.